# How could I get this child class to have this constructor when it doesn't have parameters the parent class needs?

Tags: java, constructor

I am very confused. My teacher gave us this assignment and told us we had to use the uml diagram exactly how it is, no removing or adding classes. Well I have all the requirements for my classes, but it wants me to have a child cheetah of animal that has to constructors, one with the means to call super() and one without.

```
public class Cheetah extends Animal
{

   private String name;
   private boolean isDangerous;
   private String food;
   private String soundsLike;

   public Cheetah(String n, boolean danger, String f, String sound)
   {
      this.name = n;
      this.isDangerous = danger;
      this.food = f;
      this.soundsLike = sound;
   }

   public Cheetah(String n, boolean danger, String f, String sound, double w, int a)
   {
      super(a, w);
      this.name = n;
      this.isDangerous = danger;
      this.food = f;
      this.soundsLike = sound;
   }
}
```

The parent class animal has this constructor and is not allowed to have a default constructor according to the uml diagram give to us.

```
public class Animal
{

   private int age;
   private double weight;
   private static int animalCount;

   public Animal(int age, double weight)
   {
      this.age = age;
      this.weight = weight;
   }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the first cheetah constructor without the age and weight parameters to compile, but it will not compile with the parameter how it is because the super parameters age and weight cannot be declared in that constructor. I would just make a no-arg constructor in animal, but we aren't allowed to.
[image: UML Class Diagram (I'm sorry I can't embed pictures)]

Comment: Just pass (0, 0) to the superclass constructor from the Cheetah ctor that doesn't take those params.

Comment: Thank you. I have been just staring at my code for like 2 hours trying different things. I don't know why something so simple didn't occur to me. thanks @IanKemp

Comment: No problem! BTW I don't know if that's what exactly your teacher intended - I would confirm that with him/her. (It might be a mistake on their part, or they might've wanted something else entirely.)

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly a design mistake by your teacher; an Animal is supposed to have an actual weight and an actual age, and 'uh, I dunno' is not something the system that is being designed is supposed to handle. Clearly so: After all, if that was part of the point, the provided `Animal` class would have a second constructor taking no values (which sets up age and weight to be the 'I do not know' placeholder), or at the very least there would be documentation about how to specify 'no known age' and 'no known weight', possibly as simple as containing e.g. `public static final int NO_KNOWN_AGE = -1;` for example.

Thus, you **must** have an age and a weight to make an animal. A cheetah is a kind of animal, therefore it is not possible to make a new Cheetah instance without knowing age and weight. And yet, that (String, boolean, String, String) constructor doesn't include these values, which leads to the conclusion that this was either a mistake by your teacher, or, they want to see you flail about to try to impose a lesson on API design, which is a creative didactic way to get you to realize this stuff, perhaps.

The suggestion in the comments of passing `0, 0` will indeed lead to your code compiling, but is it actually a successful completion of the assignment? Nothing says that passing 0 and 0 is a sane thing to do here. Without further context that suggests you've made a 0-age, 0-weight cheetah: Clearly an impossibility.